# How to sort an array of strings based on search keywords?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've an array of strings. I need to sort the array based on array of keywords.
The string containing max. number of keywords should come first and so on. Also, the string which contains max. no. of search keywords should come first than the number of occurrences of same search keyword. `testArray` should ignore case of `searchTerms`. If possible, you can ignore the strings which doesn't contain any search keywords in the result array.

```js
var testArray = [
    "I am",
    "I am wrong and I don't know",
    "I am right and I know",
    "I don't know",
    "I do know"
  ],
  searchTerms = ["I", "right","know"];

$.each(searchTerms, function(index, term) {
  var regX = new RegExp(term, "i");
  testArray = $.map(testArray, function(item) {
    if (regX.test(item)) {
      return item;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
});

console.log(testArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you observe in the above code, the keywords are `"I", "right","know"`. So the `testArray` results should be as below,

```
testArray = [
    "I am right and I know",    
    "I am wrong and I don't know",    
    "I don't know",
    "I do know",
    "I am"
  ]
```

string contain all the keywords come first and the other strings contain `"I","know"`, So they come next and string `"I am"` comes last as it contains only `"I"` keyword.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/iamraviteja/pen/BVjJLx?editors=0011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Idea:

- Loop over data and criteria and create a Map that has both count and value.
- Use a regex to match the string. This way you can do case-insensitive search.
- Sort this Map based on count.
- Return list of values.

```js
function getMatchCountMap(data, criterias) {
  return data.reduce((countMap, curItem) => {
    var count = criterias.filter((criteria) => new RegExp(criteria, 'i').test(curItem) ).length;
    countMap.push({
      value: curItem,
      count: count
    });
    return countMap;
  }, [])
}

function sortBasedOnCount(data, criterias) {
  var map = getMatchCountMap(data, criterias);
  map.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
  return map.map(x => x.value);
}

var testArray = [
    "I am",
    "I am wrong and I don't know",
    "I am right and I know",
    "I don't know",
    "I do know"
  ],
  searchTerms = ["I", "right","know"];
  
console.log(sortBasedOnCount(testArray, searchTerms))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the counting and sort by the count of the string.

```js
var array = [ "I am", "I am wrong and I don't know", "i am RIGHT and I know", "I don't know", "I do know", "i,i,i will come first i'm RIGHT i do KNOW"],
    search = ["I", "am","know"].map(v => v.toLowerCase()),
    count = array.reduce((c, k) => {
        var a = k.toLowerCase().split(/[^a-z0-9']+/),
            count = Object.create(null);

        a.forEach(w => count[w] = (count[w] || 0) + 1);
        c[k] = [0, 0];
        search.forEach(v => {
            c[k][0] += v in count;
            c[k][1] += count[v] || 0;
        });
        return c;
    }, Object.create(null));
  
array.sort((a, b) => count[b][0] - count[a][0] || count[b][1] - count[a][1]);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Comment: change in case not working. https://codepen.io/iamraviteja/pen/pKgZRp?editors=0011

Comment: you could normalize the search array with all lower case characters and take a lower case string for `includes`.

Comment: no. When the search words are `"I", "am", "know"`, then `"I am right and I know"`should come first but, `i,i,i will come first i'm RIGHT i do KNOW` is coming first as count of `i` is more.

Comment: what should come actually first by searching for `["I", "am", "know"]`?

Comment: `"I am right and I know"` because it contains all three search keywords

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create regex with those terms and sort by the number of matches, something like:

```js
var testArray = [
    "I am",
    "i,i,i will come first i'm RIGHT i do KNOW",
    "I am wrong and I don't know",
    "I am right and I know",
    "I don't know",
    "I do know",
    "Something else"
  ],

  searchTerms = ["I", "right", "know"];


// (?:I)|(?:right)|(?:know)
const searchExp = new RegExp(searchTerms.reduce((acc, term) => acc ? `${acc}|(?:${term})` : `(?:${term})`, ''), 'gi');

const result = testArray.sort((a, b) => {
  const bMatch = b.match(searchExp) || [];
  const aMatch = a.match(searchExp) || [];

  return bMatch.length - aMatch.length;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this fails in the case where there is no matching value. It is not able to read `.length` property for a null value (i.e. `b.match(searchExp)`).

Comment: @imixtron you are right I didn't considered that case

Comment: @J.Pichardo should ignore the case. Not working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0cLn8tee/)

Comment: @Raviteja, hmm, i didn't see that in the question.

Comment: @Raviteja, haha, no worries,  Anyway, example updated, check the `i` flag in the regexp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172483/discussion-between-raviteja-and-j-pichardo).

Comment: There is one bug. When the search keywords are `"I", "am", "know"` then `"I am right and I know"` should come first but `"i,i,i will come first i'm RIGHT i do KNOW"` is coming first as count of `i` is more.

Comment: I've updated only to clarify. If you compare the previous version youcan see it's the same. The string containing all keywords should come first. I didn't down vote.

Comment: Ok, I apologize then.